# Can we make Fingerprint Authentication App like attendence app using Fingerprint APIs

Tags: android

The Play Store Supports Fingerprint Purchase Authorizations In Android 6.0 . Does the fingerprint information stored in the Google database? If so , can we make an android attendance app which can store fingerprint information in an online database?

Answer (score 0):

No, the fingerprint data is not stored in any Google database.
It's ONLY stored locally on your device.

And you can not access the raw fingerprint data, so there is absolutely no way to save it in your own database.